# I am not able to debug the code. Tooltip is showing that breakpoint will not be hit and no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, debugging

How can I debug my code ?

I have tried to load the symbol by following below

1. `Debug>Windows?Modules`, dll name is TIT.Shared.UsrMgmt.dll
2. Before 1st step I changed the build path to `bin\`
3. Then I tried to load the symbol `pdb` file but its showing that `A matching symbol file was not found in that folder`

What is the problem here and how to resolve the same.

Below is the error while loading the symbols

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt\v4.0_1.0.0.0__eac83faa75e40932\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: PDB does not match image.
d:\perforce\build_scm_TIT_ci\Interface\Applications\TIT\main\Shared\UserMgmt\obj\Release\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\User~1.y\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb\0a3573dd4aa540abbdc5c632607f2c8c1\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\User~1.y\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb\0a3573dd4aa540abbdc5c632607f2c8c1\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TIT.Shared.UserMgmt.pdb: PDB does not match image.
```

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio?

Comment: yes visual studio 2013

Comment: Start with a small example project. Debugging works out of the box in Visual Studio, no special settings needed.

Comment: check for single slashes it is escape character...it should be\\ ..

Comment: @Drkoch : for simple project it works :) In existing project it is not working

Comment: @ShekharPankaj : In which part of code you are referring slash, please elabortate

Comment: i mean ..use bin\\ in place of bin\